# Connection error with Entity framework and class product from data layer

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture

Goal:
To use entity framework with N-tier in my WPF application.

Problem:
**I can't merge the class Product from the map ProductRepository to entity framework that also has a class named Product.**

When I tried solving the problem I always retrieve this error message:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'    D:\Arbete\kurser\C#.NET\Labbar\Lab3\ny\MediaStore\DataAccessLibrary\ProductRepository\ProductRepository.cs  45  20  DataAccessLibrary

Just a little reminder:
I would like to the class Product to be flexible that also can be used in business and presentation layer.

```
namespace DataAccessLibrary.ProductRepository
{

    public partial class Product
    {
        public Int32 ArticleNumber_id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
        public decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        //public string Book_url { get; set; }
        public Int32 ProductCategory_id { get; set; }
        public Int32 Supplier_id { get; set; }
        public Int32 Role_id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

```
namespace DataAccessLibrary.ProductRepository
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Responsible for uppdating, adding, deleting, retrieving data from product list.
    /// </summary>
    public class Productrepository : IProductrepository
    {

        private List<Product> myProductList;

        private MediaStoreEntities _myMediaStoreEntities = new MediaStoreEntities();

        public Productrepository()
        {
            myProductList = new List<Product>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all data from the product list
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list with full of product data.</returns> 
        public List<Product> GetAllProductList()
        {
            var productListt = (from a in _myMediaStoreEntities.Products
                                          select a).ToList();

            return productListt;
            //return productList;   
        }
    }
}
```

---

Class: ProductRepository
Namespace: DataAccessLibrary.ProductRepository

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve all data from the product list
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A list with full of product data.</returns> 
public List<Product> GetAllProductList()
{
    var productListt = (from a in _myMediaStoreEntities.Products
                                  select a).ToList();

    return productListt;
    //return productList;   
}
```

---

[image: aaa]
[image: bbb]
[image: ccc]

Comment: Update with extra information about the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have two `Product` classes. One in `ProductRepository` namespace and second in `Database` namespace. Both partial parts must be in the same namespace to form a single class.

If you are trying to use custom POCO class (only EFv4) you must turn off automatic code generation (you didn't because you have still .Designer.cs file under your EDMX) by removing custom tool in the designer. Then you must create custom context class derived from `ObjectContext` which will expose `ObjectSet<DataAccessLibrary.ProductRepository.Product>`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another question. From your experience in N tier. If you have a regular class named product in the datalayer. This class is also being used in presentation layer by adding reference in the library/project. The main question: is it acceptable to do it or does it break the guideline of following the N-tier's philosophy?

Comment: Is you DataAccessLibrary referenced and used from presentation layer? If yes you must access these data entities from presentation layer. How would you transfer data from DataAccessLibrary to presentation layer without these entities? Would you create another classes again in the DataAccessLibrary, map entities to these classes and pass them to presentation layer? Isn't it overkill for your application. It is used sometimes but I don't think that you need it. If DataAccessLibrary is not used directly in presentation layer you can extract entities to separate assemebly and use it in all layers.

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes, one Product.cs and one class is inside your EDMX's code behind file. And both are under different namespace.

For you , ProductRepository.Product class and EDMXNamespace.Product may look same, but for compiler, both classes are different,

```
List<ProductRepository.Product> != List<EDMXNamespace.Product>
```

There is no need to create Product.cs class at all in your ProductRepository as you are having all same fields, even if you want to create separate class, you should use some sort of constructor to copy all fields.

Comment: all project or library was created in VS2010 and the version is EF 4.0

Comment: What is content of "ProductRepository.cs 59", Does Product.cs or same named class exist in different namespace?

Comment: Please take a look at the sourcecode again. I have updated the page that answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another question. From your experience in N tier. If you have a regular class named product in the datalayer. This class is also being used in presentation layer by adding reference in the library/project. The main question: is it acceptable to do it or does it break the guideline of following the N-tier's philosophy?